# prepareForSegue: sender: alternative for popViewControllerAnimated:

Tags: objective-c, ios, tableview, segue, popviewcontroller

I'm trying to 'do some stuff' at the same time as I am popping the top viewController off the stack. Popping a viewController from the stack does not seem to be considered a segue so I can't use prepareForSegue: sender: Is there an alternative method that would fulfill my need? Or is there a different approach I could be taking?
Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are saying "pop" to the top ViewController, I assume you are using a navigationController. If that is the case, you can put whatever you want in the

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

method.

Answer (score 1):

Look for "unwinding segues" that's what fulfils your needs.